# yii Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: mysql, yii

I have a table in my mysql db

What I am trying to this. See here below the result I excpect:

average=100.1

I am trying with

```
$res = Users::model()->findAllBySql("SELECT avg(number) AS total FROM tbl_users",array());
echo $res->total;
```

but give me error Trying to get property of non-object 
when run this query in sql on php my admin its work!!

Answer (score 1):

`findAllBySql()` method returns an array.
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#findAllBySql-detail

If you want to get only one record then you shoud use `findBySql()` method.

I guess here better use DAO:

```
$res = Yii::app()->db->createCommand("SELECT avg(number) AS total FROM tbl_users")->queryRow();

if(!empty($res)){
    echo $res['total']
}
```

Comment: i am trying but give me this error Users.total not defined

Comment: i am trying but give me this error Undefined index: total

Comment: @Sepideh did you use `queryRow()` or `queryAll()` method?

Comment: @Sepideh Also make sure if table `tbl_user` has records.

Comment: @Oledje the better way is to use ->queryScalar() for this purposes. so $res will contain resulting value.

Comment: @mochalygin Yes, you right until he don't add new value in his query (for example: `"SELECT avg(number), user_name...`).

Comment: find my ansewr, i cant use findbysql in c active record and i can use create command insted                            $res=Yii::app()->db->createCommand("SELECT avg(number) AS averagetotal FROM `tbl_users`")->queryScalar(); worked

Answer (score 0):

In your Users model, define total. If you use alias in query, you need to define it in the model else it will give you this error. That is the reason it works in phpmyadmin but not here.

```
class Users  extends CActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @return string the associated database table name
     */
    public $total; // define total here 
    public function tableName()
    {
```